# SPListItem field resets to null after calling Update

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, updatelistitems

I use SharePoint 2013 with the following code:

```
SPListItem listItem;
...
listItem["MyCol"] = " "; // Space character.
Console.WriteLine($"listItem[\"MyCol\"] = {listItem["MyCol"]}"); // Here i see the space character.
listItem.Update();
Console.WriteLine($"listItem[\"MyCol\"] = {listItem["MyCol"]}"); // Here value is became null.
```

Looks like issue reproduces only for space character.

Comment: What is the data type pf your `MyCol`??

Answer (score 1):

you have to execute your query with  clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

```
ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
oListItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the below explanation, you need to call `ExecuteQuery()` to take effect of `Update()` call.

> To set most list item properties, you can use a column indexer to make an assignment, and call the [Update()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee536748%28v%3doffice.14%29) method so that changes will take effect when you call [ExecuteQuery()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee545848%28v%3doffice.14%29) or [ExecuteQueryAsync(ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler, ClientRequestFailedEventHandler)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee667318%28v%3doffice.14%29).

**Source**: [Updating a list item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539976(v=office.14)#updating-a-list-item).

Try your code like below:

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
SPListItem listItem;
...
listItem["MyCol"] = " "; // Space character.
Console.WriteLine($"listItem[\"MyCol\"] = {listItem["MyCol"]}"); // Here i see the space character.
listItem.Update();

clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //Call this method before writing the value to Console.

Console.WriteLine($"listItem[\"MyCol\"] = {listItem["MyCol"]}"); // Here value is became null.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, if the current user does not have appropriate rights then also it won't allow you to update.
Kindly keep your code enclosed within *RunWithElevatedPrivileges* which uses System User Account

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){ //your code  });
```